# How to retrive softlayer ticket owner using api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using python client and running the below slcli command, its  providing other details without owner information. please guide me how to retrieve the SL ticket owner .

slcli ticket detail --count 100 29652621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the next command:

> slcli call-api Ticket getAssignedUser -–id=29652621

The command retrieves the SoftLayer_User_Customer object to which the ticket was assigned.

Refer to the next links for further information:
http://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/?highlight=call-api
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Ticket/getAssignedUser